# Как сделать checkbox с 3 вариантами, как на картинке?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать подобный checkbox? Как правильно погуглить? Есть ли готовые решения? Нужен чистый css + html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее это radio.

Comment: используйте `<label for="">`, скрытые `<input type="radio">`  внутри  этих `label` и `css` `input[type="radio"]:checked`

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мой вариант (впервые такое делаю, было интересно).

```css
.radio-wrap
{
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #F1F0F4;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgb(144 146 153 / 60%);
}


.radio-label > span
{
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  user-select: none;
  color: #C7C9CF;
}

.radio-label > input
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.radio-label > input:checked + span
{
  color: #FB7E39;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgb(199 201 207 / 60%);
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-wrap">
  <label class="radio-label">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="category">
    <span>Category</span>
  </label>
  
  <label class="radio-label">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="period" checked>
    <span>Period</span>
  </label>
  
  <label class="radio-label">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="alphabet">
    <span>Alphabet</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Если кто-то знает, что я в целом не правильно делаю, дайте знать. Например было интересно, как это правильно написать по бэму.

Comment: Курсором тянулся к плюсику, пока не прочел ["по бэму"](https://i.imgur.com/PwQ9r3K.gif)... _шучу))_

Comment: @yar85 А что не так в бэме?))

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, БЭМ сам по себе ок в плане идей, мне просто индивидуально не нравится его применение конкретно **в верстке**. Чем именно - тем что игнорирует фундаментальные принципы CSS (каскадирование) в попытке натянуть на технологию "типа объектный" подход, для которого она вообще никак не предназначена. Это выглядит нелепо, и работает соответствующе. Ну и еще именование классов всратое (простите мой французский) - префиксное гораздо лаконичнее/приятнее, и успешно решает те же самые задачи разделения сущностей. //Все написанное - лишь субъективное мнение! Да простят меня БЭМовцы за него.

Comment: @yar85, я не против БЭМ и не За него. На данный момент у меня не было заказов и я не знаю как правильнее делать. Но было бы интересно услышать как нужно/можно.

Comment: @Oliver, по БЭМ:
`.toggle-switch>label.toggle-switch__option*3>(input[type=radio].toggle-switch__radio+span.toggle-switch__label)`, класс активного варианта `.toggle-switch__option--active`.
По префиксной:
`.c-toggle-switch>label.o-option*3>(input[type=radio].r-state+span.o-label)`, класс активного варианта `.is-active`.
Префиксных схем много, они все похожи. Здесь я (скромно так) привожу лишь одну, автором которой являюсь - называю ее CORE (Component, Objects, Roles, Extras). Она еще в закрытой бете, но надеюсь когда-нибудь все же отрелизю ее публичный репо и оф.сайтик с доками/гæдлайном.

Comment: @Oliver, Преимущество префиксных схем (помимо лаконичности) в том, что их можно читать на языке приближенном к естественному. Если смотреть только на классы в emmet/pug-выражении, типа `.c-toggle-switch>.o-option*3>(.r-state+.o-label)` - его можно прочесть примерно как 
"Component ToggleSwitch with (Option objects with (<any> as State) and Label object)". Попробуй-ка так сделать с БЭМом ;)

Comment: Возможно вы все же правы, но это нужно вникать. Как минимум для себя выучить и то и то, чтобы понять, что будет лучше.

Comment: @Oliver, да, безусловно, тут я не пытаюсь заявлять что "есть лишь озин истинный путь, а остальные еретические" - каждый сам волен выбирать то что ему по душе, то что индивидуально комфортно и подходит наилучшим образом.