# Как создать кнопки, которыми можно переключаться?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я начинающий веб-разработчик. Для практики верстаю сайт. При верстке наткнулся на 2 кнопки, которые вероятно должны переключаться между собой.Облазил ютуб, но там было что-то подобное:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Вроде бы то что надо, но не знал как реализовать. с JavaScript я знаком, но работать с ним пока еще не умею. Как быть? [image: Вот этот переключатель]

Comment: Думаю в данном вопросе +- такая же задача: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301015/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-checkbox-%d1%81-3-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5/1301048#1301048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.toggle-switch
{
    display: inline-flex;

    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;

    background-color: #F7F7FB;
    border: 1px solid #3CAEFB;

    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.toggle-switch__radio
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle-switch__label
{
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    user-select: none;
    color: #1C1C1E;
}

.toggle-switch__option:first-child .toggle-switch__label
{
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.toggle-switch__option:last-child .toggle-switch__label
{
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}


.toggle-switch__radio:checked + .toggle-switch__label
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #5454D4;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-switch">
    <label class="toggle-switch__option">
        <input type="radio" name="view" class="toggle-switch__radio" checked>
        <span class="toggle-switch__label">Yearly</span>
    </label>

    <label class="toggle-switch__option">
        <input type="radio" name="view" class="toggle-switch__radio">
        <span class="toggle-switch__label">Monthly</span>
    </label>
</div>
```